# Narrow matrix by conditional restrictions

Tags: r, arrays, string, matrix, character

Let's consider vector following and it's combination matrix representation:

```
string_vec <- c("huge", "small", "small_very", "something", "big_huge", "big_very", "tremendous", 
                "huge_big", "huge_amount", "small_amout", "else", "something_big", "something_small")
combinations <- utils::combn(string_vec, 6)
```

And let's define vector

`a = c("huge", big")`

I want now to restrict my matrix to have at least one element from the family of elements of `a`.

i.e. I want to have at  least one element starting with `huge` (so those elements are: `"huge", "huge_big", "huge_amount"`) and at least one with `big` `("big_huge", "big_very")`.

Do you have any idea how it can be obtained ?

**EDIT**

I figure out that we can use `apply` wiht `startsWith`:

```
combinations <- combinations[,colSums(apply(combinations, 2, function(x) startsWith(x, "huge")))==1]
combinations <- combinations[,colSums(apply(combinations, 2, function(x) startsWith(x, "big")))==1]
```

But I found this solution highly inefficient, due to the fact that I have to make each step manually for each family (in longer family vector it could be very problematic)

Answer (score 1):

We could `paste` the 'a' vector to create a single string, use that as `pattern` in `grepl`, loop over the columns of the `matrix` (either `base R` `apply`) or `dapply` from `collapse` (would be more efficient), check if there `any` matches in those columns, and subset the columns with the logical output

```
library(collapse)
out <- combinations[,dapply(combinations, FUN = 
    function(x) any(grepl(paste(a, collapse='|'), x)), MARGIN = 2)]
```

---

If we want to find at least one of the elements from all elements of 'a'

```
out <- combinations[,dapply(combinations, FUN = 
    function(x) Reduce(`&`, lapply(a, function(u) any(grepl(u, x)))), MARGIN = 2)]
dim(out)
#[1]    6 1555
```

---

If it is to check elements that starts with those words in 'a', `paste` with `^`

```
out <- combinations[,dapply(combinations, FUN = 
     function(x) Reduce(`&`, lapply(paste0('^', a), 
       function(u) any(grepl(u, x)))), MARGIN = 2)]
dim(out)
#[1]    6 1072
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `combn`

```
(cbs <- combn(string_vec, 6))[
    ,
    colSums(matrix(grepl("^huge", cbs), nrow = 6)) > 0
    & colSums(matrix(grepl("^big", cbs), nrow = 6)) > 0
]
```

Comment: Are you sure this code is working ? I run it on the three dimensional case: 
`(cbs <- combn(string_vec,3))[,colSums(matrix(grepl("^(huge|big)",cbs),nrow = 3))>0]`. 
Have a look at very last element
`cbs[, 286]` `"else"            "something_big"   "something_small"` which is not part of `big` or `huge` family.

Comment: @John Yes, I think it's working. `^(huge|big)` checks if values start with `huge` or `big`.

Comment: Yes you're right! I must used your code improperly. However your code returns for exmple: `"big_huge"        "something_big"   "something_small"` which doesn't contain element of `huge` family.

Comment: @John Okey, I see. Now check out my update.